# Covering all the edges of a hypercube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Consider an arbitrary $n$- dimensional hypercube:

If we select $n - 1$ corners of that hypercube and highlight all $(n - 2)$ dimensional elements that originate from each of the corners is it possible to cover all the $(n - 2)$ dimensional faces of the cube? Also, is it ever possible to cover all the faces originating from a corner besides one of the $n - 1$ originally selected?

Some insight:

I failed to cover all the edges of a cube using 2 points and the set of edges extended from them. The same applies for the case squares and lower.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is true in general for all dimensions N (the first one). The second one i'm feeling pretty strong about as well.

Comment: Is $n$ the dimension of the hypercube? If so, can you edit that into the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-hypercube has $2n(n-1)\ \ \ \ (n-2)$-faces. Each corner touches $2n-3\ \ \ \ (n-2)$-faces. At most $(2n-3)(n-1)$ faces are covered, and at least $3(n-1)$ remain uncovered.

Comment: Why isn't it 2n choose 2 faces?

Comment: For the number from each corner?

Comment: I copied your convention of calling $(2n-2)$-D elements faces. Even for a cube, there are $3$ edges from each corner, and ${2n\choose 2} =15 \not= 3$.

Comment: My mistake I meant n choose 2

Comment: And I'll explain my thoughts which were there are n (n-1) dimensional faces at each corner so we select 2 of them to produce an (n-2) dimensional face

Comment: Do you have a proof of the 2n - 3 count? I would really like to see it :)